# Load disparate views based on user name using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, authentication

I have created a student and teacher feedback system using PHP and MySQL. Students and lecturers should be shown a separate view once they login. A students username takes the form of `B********` and a lecturers' username takes the form of `E********`. I'm thinking is there a way to take the user inputed username and to truncate it and match the `B` or `E` and then serve up the relevant PHP view for the given user or is there a better way to achieve what I'm after. I'm relatively new to PHP so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You Can use flags for the users. For example, -s for student and -l for lecturer. Then when the user logs in and you check the password, check the flag too, serve the view determained by the flag.

Answer (score 2):

Below would be my approach:

1. In the database, make a "userType" column that indicates whether a username belongs to a student or a teacher.
2. User submits their login details. You find a match, check the "userType" column and display a view accordingly.

Here's a very basic example with code

```
$sql = $this->db->query("
 SELECT userType
 FROM userTable
 WHERE userName = //Username typed in by the user
 AND password = //Password typed in by the user
");
$result = $sql->fetchAll();
if($result[0][0] == "student") include_once "student.php";
if($result[0][0] == "teacher") include_once "teacher.php";
else echo "User does not exist";
```

Comment: So, at the minute I have set up a table for the students and one for the lecturers. One containing StudentID and one containing LecturerID. If this is the case, do I need a userType class to tell the difference between them or could I just so something like 

`IF
  SELECT StudentID from Student;
 THEN
  include student.php;
 ELSE
 IF 
  SELECT LecturerID from Lecturer;
 THEN
  include lecturer.php;
 ELSE
  PRINT 'You have entered an incorrect user ID';`

Or is this totally wrong?

Comment: I suggest that you go with one table for both and use a "userType" column to differentiate between them. This way your DB design will be cleaner and queries will be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the first character of a string with array access syntax `[]`, string access syntax `{}`, and a variety of other methods.

```
if ("B" == $name[0]) {
    // show student page
}
else {
   // show instructor page
}
```

Comment: What's up with the yoda condition ? http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html

Comment: "Is red the color?" is in no way more easily understood than "Is the color red?"

Comment: @DusteD you can read it however you want, but `"B" = $name[0]` is a syntax error.  `$name[0] = "B"` is always `true`

Answer (score -1):

```
if ( $username[0] == 'E' )
{
  // It's a teacher
} else if ( $username[0] == 'B' )
{
  // It's a student
} else {
  // Username is invalid
}
```